# mysql return two columns based on same field

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
(case when tableA.gender = 'Male' then tableB.X) as Male, 
(case when tableA.gender = 'Female' then tableB.X) as Female

...
FROM (MANY TABLES JOINT)
...

GROUP BY tableB.X
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

I'm trying to return two columns based on one field (column_name) by querying whether another column (tableB.X) is 'Male' or 'Female'. How do I do this? I would still need to order in DESC for both columns too. Thank you.

Every row returned as a value and a gender (2 columns). I am trying to split the value into two columns based on the gender and then display in descending order of counts by each splitted column..

i.e. input table:

```
value     Gender
-----     ------
AAA       Male
BBB       Female
AAA       Male
CCC       Male
AAA       Female
BBB       Female
```

i.e. output table:

```
Rank      Male      Female
----      ----      ------
 1        AAA       BBB          (AAA because it has 2 male occurences, BBB has 2 female occurences)
 2        CCC       AAA          (1 occurence each for male and female, ordered descending order)
```

I also do not know how many different values there are/will be, so SQL would have to do the count for me. I am able to get the results using two queries, by using WHERE gender = male and WHERE gender = female but I'm seeking to know whether I can do it in one query instead.. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Because this doesn't currently make sense. For example, if my table has 'Alice','Female' and 'Bob','Male' - what rows do you expect to have in this SELECT's result? Will you have one row with Male='Bob' and Female='Alice'? Or do you expect to have one row with Male='Bob' and Female=NULL, and another row with Male=NULL and Female='Alice'?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output that you are looking for?  Like PaF said, this isn't currently very clear.

Comment: Since you have added example data to your question I am reading your problem differently now. I dont see any connection between the Male and Female columns though. Would it be ok to just select all males, then do a ranking on them and afterwards repeat the same thing for all females? The result is not in one table then, but that could be fixed separately.

Comment: yep, I am able to do that :) I was just wondering if that could be accomplished using SQL

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that is possible with a `UNION` statement. The following is not tested though:

```
SELECT
tableB.X as Male,
'' as Female
FROM
...
tableB JOIN tableA
...
WHERE tableA.gender = 'male'

UNION

SELECT
'' as Male,
tableB.X as Female
FROM
...
tableB JOIN tableA
...
WHERE tableA.gender = 'female'
```

Instead of an empty string `''` you might also be able to use `NULL`.

Comment: It works in combining, but would it be possible not to have any null rows? I would like to sort all according to their number of occurences in descending order by each column after they have been segregated..

Comment: Building on my idea above: `SELECT id, Sum(Male), Sum(Female) FROM MY_STATEMENT_ABOVE GROUP BY id ORDER BY Male`. You would have to add another column (here called `id` in the inner statement) and probably replace `''` with `0`.